# Lying over properties with integral extensions of rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $A\subset B$ be an integral extension of rings and let $\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}(A)$. Setting $S=A\setminus\mathfrak{p}$ and $A_\mathfrak{p}=S^{-1}A$, if $\mathfrak{q}\subset B$ lies over $\mathfrak{p}$, is it necessarily true that there is some $Q\in\text{Spec}(S^{-1}B)$ which lies over $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}(A_\mathfrak{p})$?

I'm having tremendous difficulty parsing this. I know that the inclusion goes the 'other way', though. I know that if there is $Q\in\text{Spec}(S^{-1}B)$ that lies over $\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, then $Q\cap B$ lies over $\mathfrak{p}$. (because we know that $\text{Spec}(S^{-1}B)\to\text{Spec}(B)$ is injective).

Comment: $q\cap A=p\implies S^{-1}q\cap S^{-1}A=S^{-1}p$. Take $Q=S^{-1}q$.

Comment: I think what I was failing to see is that $\mathfrak{q}$ is in the image of the canonical map on spectra $\text{Spec}(S^{-1}B)\to\text{Spec}(B)$. Thanks!